# Can we use bootstrap grid system to control div width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has a good grid system to split a `div` into 12 divisions. Thus, sometimes, I am intended to use it anywhere when I want to split a `div` into 2 or 3 equal sub `div`s. Just use `col-sm-4` or `col-sm-6`. But our senior engineer told us, never ever try to use grid system to control `div` width unless where you really need grid system to layout for different devices(Laptop, tablet, mobile). Instead, use fixed `div` `width` or other ways. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your senior engineer needs to read bootstrap documentation

Comment: I don't think it's such a big deal, but isn't setting "width: 33%" more convenient?